# How to start pm2 with arguments?

Tags: node.js, parse-server, pm2, parse-dashboard

I have a simple command that works fine when run:

```
parse-dashboard --config /home/ubuntu/dash/config.json
```

However, when running it with pm2, it doesn't work:

```
pm2 start parse-dashboard -- --config=/home/ubuntu/dash/config.json
```

looking at the logs, i get the error:
 `node: bad option: --config=/home/ubuntu/dash/config.json`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a process file where you specify the arguments. Create the following file and name it for example `ecosystem.json` (make sure the 'script' and 'cwd' (where the app will be launched) locations are correct for you))

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "parse-dashboard-wrapper",
    "script"      : "/usr/bin/parse-dashboard",
    "watch"       : true,
    "cwd"         : "/home/parse/parse-dashboard",
    "args"        : "--config /home/ubuntu/dash/config.json"
  }]
}
```

And run it with

`pm2 start ecosystem.json`

Comment: is it not possible to do this via CLI? I really don't want to do this via a json file.

Comment: Check out these docs for doing it via CLI:
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/pm2-how-to-start-your-app-with-node-js-v8-arguments